# ajaxing onbeforeunload in Firefox 15

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, windows, firefox

I'm having issues with firefox 15.0.1 when I attempt to perform an ajax "fire and forget" call. Basically when the user closes the page or redirects, I want to perform an ajax call. In Chrome and IE, this appears to work fine when I view my requests in Charles. However, in FireFox, I'm not seeing my ajax call being made.

```
jQuery(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
     jQuery.ajax({url:'some page', type: 'GET', dataType: 'script'});
});
```

I know the event works when I include a console.log or an alert. There just doesn't seem like there's enough time allowed to perform this ajax call before unload. Anyone have any thoughts on this or have a workaround?

Comment: AJAX calls will be aborted if the page is left before the call is completed. I think the only solution you'd have is to make it synchronous, but that's not ideal

Comment: I wish I knew of a way to "fire and forget" like you mention, but I don't think you can override that behavior of the browser to automatically abort if you leave the page too quickly. I'm not sure if this would work, and it definitely wouldn't be full-proof, but if you sent the AJAX request, then ran a while loop for so many seconds (say 1 second), it would stop the browser from exiting (and would "freeze" the page/user, so it could be annoying), but it might leave enough time for the AJAX request to make it to the server (hopefully). Again, not ideal

Answer (score 0):

You can create another html page that would perform the ajax call, which would be called from the onbeforeunload event.

That new page would perform the action and close as soon as it completes.

Another way would be to use synchronous ajax call as shown below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url:    'http://abcexample.com/getInfo',
     success: function(result) {
                  if(result.isOk == false)
                      alert(result.message);
              },
     async:   false
});
```

But the synchronous call would wait for the call to be completed before going further. If you would like to execute and forget about what the ajax call does, then the 1st method would work great.